# Estimation of function using Spline Interpolation

Tags: splines, approximation, interpolation

My problem is the following:
Estimate the function from given data (below) and show that the estimated function has the following properties: (i) $f(0)=0$ (ii) $f(x)>0, x>0$ and $f(x)<0, x<0$. In order to estimate the function I've tried to use Lagrange Polynomial Interpolation technique, but the interpolant wasn't even closer since I've more than 100 data points (Runge's phenomenon). The second technique that I've tried was polynomial regression, but that technique can't be applied since for the estimated function $f(0)$ is not equal to 0 (since unlike Lagrange Polynomial Interpolation, the polynomial regression doesn't require that fitted line should pass through every single point). The third technique that supposedly could be useful is Spline Interpolation (but I have only basic knowledge about it).  Which technique I have to choose in order to estimate function, which satisfies the above mentioned properties. Is it possible to see the functional form of Spline Interpolant?

[image: Data generated from some process, which is needed to estimate]

Comment: why don't u just use a linear interpolation? the function seems to be observed without an error on a nicely narrow grid.

Comment: @chRrr Do you think that estimating function using linear interpolation will satisfy $f(0)=0$ condition? Thank you.

Comment: @chRrr Than you very much, It works.

Comment: @chRrr One more question, I am using "approxfun" in R to estimate linear interpolant. Is there any way to see the functional form of interpolant explicitly? Thank you.

Comment: Nice to hear that you immediately get $f(0)=0$. unfortunately you don't get an explicit functional form from R. But since approxfun correspondends just to a linear interpolation of two points, you have for $x \in [x_i, x_{i+1}]:$ $$ \widehat{f}(x) = f(x_i) + (x-x_i)  \frac{f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)}{x_{i+1}-x_i}, $$ i.e. your estimated function has as many cases as there are points to be interpolated.

An alternative is $splinefun$ in $R$, which fits an interpolating cubic spline, however, your observation grid is pretty dense and i think a linear interpolation might be fine here.

Comment: @chRrr Thank you very much for your comment. I've tries splinefun in R, it suits as well. Is there any opportunity to see functional form explicitly?

Comment: Sure--but a piecewise cubic spline of these data has about 100 parameters.  It's unlikely you would find an explicit representation to be of interest and it's certain you won't find it useful for answering the questions you posted.  Indeed, your questions are directly answerable without approximating the data with any function at all. You only need to partition the x-coordinates according to the sign of the corresponding y-coordinates and draw the (obvious) conclusions.